# Не работает rewrite SEO URL's для стандартных страниц

Tags: url, opencart, чпу

Добрый день! Помогите пожалуйста. 
На opencart магазине, стоит vqmod и pavblog. 
Мне нужно сделать ЧПУ ссылки для таких страниц как contact-us, sitemap и т.д. 
нашёл простенькое решение которое заработало на чистом opencart. 
на реальном магазине стоит vqmod и pavblog, не работает. 
Сделал вот что : 
подключил родной котроллер common/seo_url вместо pavblog/seo в index.php
подключил к seo_url код, чтобы он мог работать и для pavblog и для родных opencart ссылок.

```
<?php сlass ControllerCommonSeoUrl extends Controller {
public function index() {
    // Add rewrite to url class
    if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
        $this->url->addRewrite($this);
    }

    // Decode URL
    if (isset($this->request->get['_route_'])) {
        $parts = explode('/', $this->request->get['_route_']);
        /** BEGIN PROCESSING TO DECORD REQUET SEO URL FOR PAVO BLOG MODULE **/
        $blogConfig = $this->config->get('pavblog');
        $seo = isset($blogConfig['keyword_listing_blogs_page'])?trim($blogConfig['keyword_listing_blogs_page']):"blogs";
        if( $this->request->get['_route_'] == $seo ){
        $this->request->get['route'] = 'pavblog/blogs';
        return $this->forward($this->request->get['route']);
        } /** END OF PROCESSING TO DECORD REQUET SEO URL FOR PAVO BLOG MODULE **/ 

        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($part) . "'");

            if ($query->num_rows) {
                $url = explode('=', $query->row['query']);

                if ($url[0] == 'product_id') {
                    $this->request->get['product_id'] = $url[1];
                }

                if ($url[0] == 'category_id') {
                    if (!isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                        $this->request->get['path'] = $url[1];
                    } else {
                        $this->request->get['path'] .= '_' . $url[1];
                    }
                }   

                if ($url[0] == 'manufacturer_id') {
                    $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'] = $url[1];
                }

                if ($url[0] == 'information_id') {
                    $this->request->get['information_id'] = $url[1];
                }   

                /** BEGIN PROCESSING TO DECORD REQUET SEO URL FOR PAVO BLOG MODULE **/
                if( count($url) == 2 && ( preg_match( "#pavblog#", $url[0] )) ){
                $this->request->get['route'] = $url[0];
                $this->request->get['id'] = $url[1];
                } /** END OF PROCESSING TO DECORD REQUET SEO URL FOR PAVO BLOG MODULE **/
            } else {
                $this->request->get['route'] = 'error/not_found';   
            }
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/category';
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/manufacturer/info';
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'information/information';
        } else {
            echo "pered query";
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($this->request->get['_route_']) . "'");
            echo "posle query";                
            if ($query->num_rows) {
                $this->request->get['route'] = $query->row['query'];

            }
       }

        if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
            return $this->forward($this->request->get['route']);
        }
    }
}

public function rewrite($link) {
    $url_info = parse_url(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $link));

    $url = ''; 

    $data = array();

    parse_str($url_info['query'], $data);

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($data['route'])) {
            if (($data['route'] == 'product/product' && $key == 'product_id') || (($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer/info' || $data['route'] == 'product/product') && $key == 'manufacturer_id') || ($data['route'] == 'information/information' && $key == 'information_id')) {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($key . '=' . (int)$value) . "'");

                if ($query->num_rows) {
                    $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                    unset($data[$key]);
                }                   
            } elseif ($key == 'path') {
                $categories = explode('_', $value);

                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = 'category_id=" . (int)$category . "'");

                    if ($query->num_rows) {
                        $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
                    }                           
                }

                unset($data[$key]);
            }
            elseif ($key == 'route') {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($data['route']) . "'");

                    if ($query->num_rows) {
                        $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                        unset($data[$key]);
                         echo "this is root: $url <br>";
                    }

            }
        }
    }   

    /** BEGIN PROCESSING TO REWRITE SEO URL FOR  PAVO BLOG MODULE **/
    if ( ( preg_match( "#pavblog#", $data['route'] ))  && isset($data['id']) ) { 
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape( $data['route'] . '=' .$data['id']) . "'");
        if ($query->num_rows) {
            $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
            unset($data[$key]);
            unset($data['id']);
        }                   
    }  else if( $data['route'] == 'pavblog/blogs' ){ 
        $blogConfig = $this->config->get('pavblog');
        $seo = isset($blogConfig['keyword_listing_blogs_page'])?trim($blogConfig['keyword_listing_blogs_page']):"blogs"; 
        $url .= '/'.$seo;
    }
    /** END OF PROCESSING SEO URL FOR PAVO BLOG MODULE **/

    if ($url) {
        unset($data['route']);

        $query = '';

        if ($data) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $query .= '&' . $key . '=' . $value;
            }

            if ($query) {
                $query = '?' . trim($query, '&');
            }
        }

        return $url_info['scheme'] . '://' . $url_info['host'] . (isset($url_info['port']) ? ':' . $url_info['port'] : '') . str_replace('/index.php', '', $url_info['path']) . $url . $query;
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}   }?>
```

Всё работает и ЧПУ pavblog и ЧПУ opencart. Но почему то не меняются ссылки у Contact Us, Sitemap, короче у всего футера, кроме тех ссылок что в колонке Information. Сделал var_dump того, что должно прийти в качестве замены из url_alias - вроде приходит то что надо. Но в строке адреса ничего не меняется. :(( Не знаю что искать, где копать ? Помогите :(